# Can't cast char to unsigned char?

Tags: serial

```
byte RSV_Resp_test[3] = {'a', 'b', 0};
Serial.println(reinterpret_cast<char>(RSV_Resp_test[1]));
```

produces the error

```
error: invalid cast from type 'byte {aka unsigned char}' to type 'char'
Serial.println(reinterpret_cast<char>(RSV_Resp_test[1]));
                                                      ^
```

How can this be an ill-formed cast?  I just need to print the value as a ascii character, not as a number.

Answer (score 0):

```
Serial.println(static_cast<char>(RSV_Resp_test[1]));
```

works.  I still don't understand why the reinterpret_cast errors out.

Comment: This may help shed light on it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332030/when-should-static-cast-dynamic-cast-const-cast-and-reinterpret-cast-be-used - summary: `static_cast` is what you normally want in 99% of situations and is what you need here. `reinterpret_cast` is only used when you want to do really strange things.

Comment: In a bit of standardization weirdness, section 5.2.10 [expr.reinterpret.cast] says only certain kinds of reinterpret casts are allowed!? Maybe it is time to move back to 'C'.

Comment: Personally I never use them and just use `(char)varname` instead.